# How to combine two JavaScript code blocks

Tags: javascript, datatables

I am new on javascript and I am trying to combine 2 javascript blocks but I am falling apart?

**FIRST BLOCK**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Setup - add a text input to each footer cell
    $('table.table tfoot th').each( function () {
        var title = $(this).text();
        $(this).html( '<input type="text" placeholder="'+title+' ARA" />' );
    } );

    // DataTable
    var table = $('table.table').DataTable();

    // Apply the search
    table.columns().every( function () {
        var that = this;

        $( 'input', this.footer() ).on( 'keyup change', function () {
            if ( that.search() !== this.value ) {
                that
                    .search( this.value )
                    .draw();
            }
        } );
    } );
} );
</script>
```

**SECOND BLOCK**

```
$('table.table').DataTable({
"order": [
  [0, "desc"]
],
paging: true,
"oLanguage": {
  "sUrl": "js/dil/LANGUAGE.json",
}
} );
```

I want to add "oLanguage" and "order" lines to first javascript. What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

Just copy-paste array from `DataTables` to first part:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Setup - add a text input to each footer cell
    $('table.table tfoot th').each(function () {
        $(this).html('<input type="text" placeholder="'+$(this).text()+' ARA" />');
    });

    // DataTable
    var table = $('table.table').DataTable({
        order: [
          [0, "desc"]
        ],
        paging: true,
        oLanguage: {
          sUrl: "js/dil/LANGUAGE.json",
        }
    });

    // Apply the search
    table.columns().every(function () {
        var that = this;

        $('input', this.footer()).on('keyup change', function () {
            if (that.search() !== this.value ) {
                that
                    .search( this.value )
                    .draw();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

---

**Note** DataTables used to have it's variables in hUngarianNotation and later on moved to camlCase, so it's most likely your `oLanguage` is not recognized by new API

Comment: +$(this).text()+  doesnt show the seacrh results? others are working